# Difference between char and character objects

Tags: r

[From the language definition](https://cran.r-project.org/doc/manuals/r-release/R-lang.html#Objects):

> "char": a ‘scalar’ string object (internal only) ***
>   "character": a vector containing character values
>
> Users cannot easily get hold of objects of types marked with a ‘***’.

```
y <- "My name is hasnain"
class(y)
```

The class functions tells that 'y' belongs to the character class. What I have perceived is that 'y' is an object which is of char type and it belongs to character class. Does the character object also belongs to the character class?

Comment: There are no scalar object types in R. `typeof(y)` returns "character". I don't know where you got this quote from, but "internal" probably refers to underlying C code.

Comment: @Roland http://archive.linux.duke.edu/cran/doc/manuals/r-release/R-lang.html#Objects     page# 5

Comment: "'y' is an object which is of char type" That's not correct. It's of type "character".

Comment: On further reflection, I think, you've asked actually a good, interesting question. I have absolutely no idea how one could get an object of type "char"  in R. I might add a bounty asking for an example, if nobody posts an answer.

Answer (score 33, accepted):

The two R types `char` and `character` at the internal C side correspond to `CHARSXP` and `STRSXP` respectively. At the R level, one always deals with `character` objects; a single string, like:

```
y <- "My name is hasnain"
```

is actually a `character` object of length 1. Internally, each element of a `character` is a `char`, but R doesn't provide (AFAIK) a direct way to extract, create and/or use a `char`.

Although you can't create a `char`/`CHARSXP` object with pure R, it's straightforward to get it through the R/C interface using the `mkChar` function, which takes a standard C string and turns it into a `CHARSXP`. For instance, one can create a `char.c` file:

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <stdlib.h>
#include <R.h>
#include <Rinternals.h>
SEXP returnCHAR() {
   SEXP ret = PROTECT(mkChar("Hello World!"));
   UNPROTECT(1);
   return ret;
}
```

After compiling it through `R CMD SHLIB char.c`, from the R side:

```
dyn.load("char.so")  #linux dll; extension varies across platforms
x<-.Call("returnCHAR")
x
# <CHARSXP: "Hello World!">
typeof(x)
#[1] "char"
length(x)
#[1] 12
```

Besides `typeof` and `length` I didn't find many other R functions that acts on `char` objects. Even `as.character` doesn't work! I could neither extract a `char` from a standard `character` vector, nor insert this `char` into an existing `character` vector (assignment doesn't work).

The `c` function coerces to a `list` if an object is a `char`:

```
c(1,"a",x)
#[[1]]
#[1] 1
#
#[[2]]
#[1] "a"
#
#[[3]]
#<CHARSXP: "Hello World!">
```

We can make use of `.Internal(inspect())` (warning: `inspect` is an internal, not exposed function and so it might change in future releases. Don't rely on it) to have a glimpse of the internal structure of an object. As far as I know, `char`/`CHARXSP` objects are shared between string vectors to save memory. For instance:

```
let<-letters[1:2]
.Internal(inspect(let))
#@1aff2a8 16 STRSXP g0c2 [NAM(1)] (len=2, tl=0)
#  @1368c60 09 CHARSXP g0c1 [MARK,gp=0x61] [ASCII] [cached] "a"
#  @16dc7c0 09 CHARSXP g0c1 [MARK,gp=0x60] [ASCII] [cached] "b"
mya<-"a"
.Internal(inspect(mya))
#@3068710 16 STRSXP g0c1 [NAM(3)] (len=1, tl=0)
#  @1368c60 09 CHARSXP g0c1 [MARK,gp=0x61] [ASCII] [cached] "a"
```

From the above output, we note two things:

- `STRSXP` objects are vectors of `CHARSXP` objects, as we mentioned;
- strings are stored in a "global pool": the `"a"` string is stored at the same address despite being created independently in two different objects.

Comment: Great answer! One thing I think might improve it is addressing OP's confusion as to `"My name is hasnain"` being a character vector of length one rather than a `char` object

Answer (score 0):

As per [nicola's answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/57886846/5977215)

> The two R types char and character at the internal C side correspond to CHARSXP and STRSXP respectively. At the R level, one always deals with character objects; a single string, like:

```
y <- "My name is hasnain"
```

In R, a piece of text is represented as a sequence of characters (letters, numbers, and symbols). The data type R provides for storing sequences of characters is character. Formally, the mode of an object that holds character strings in R is "character".

A character object is used to represent string values in R. We convert objects into character values with the as.character() function:

```
> x = as.character(3.14) 
> x              # print the character string 
[1] "3.14" 
> class(x)       # print the class name of x 
[1] "character"
```

Character/string – each element in the vector is a string of one or more characters.
Built in character vectors are letters and LETTERS which provide the 26 lower (and upper)
case letters, respecitively.

```
> y = c("a", "bc", "def")
> length(y)
[1] 3
> nchar(y)
[1] 1 2 3
> y == "a"
[1] TRUE FALSE FALSE
> y == "b"
[1] FALSE FALSE FALSE
```

It is as simple as that yes you've perceived right that y is an object of type char ad belongs to character/string class but if and only if 'a' here the sequence of chars forming a string/character